# A different way for converting to 2's complement

Tags: conversion, binary

One way to convert any number to 2's complement is by adding the number to 256, if the number can be represented by 8 bit number. For example if we want to convert -100 to 2's complement we do addition with 256 to get 156, which has a binary value of 10011100, but if we do binary conversion while considering this as a 2's complement number we will get -128+16+8+4 = -100. If seems to be working as I am getting wring answers, but I am not able to figure out why this works, what the math/logic behind the adding a 8 bit number. Any help/direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is how 2's complement is designed: if you start at 0 and add 1, you get the value 1, if you substract 1, you get the value -1. 0b0000_0000 - 1 = 0b1111_1111 (which is 255 when interpreted as unsigned). Hence you can calculate 0b1_0000_0000 - N to get ( - N ).